# How to get the text in between heading (h3) tags?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

We have a data like this:

```
<h3>title1</h3>
<p> paragraph 1<p>
<p> paragraph 2<p>
<p> paragraph 3<p>
<h3>title2</h3>
<p> paragraph 4<p>
<p> paragraph 5<p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
     </tr>
</table>
<h3>title3</h3>
<p> paragraph 6<p>
<p> paragraph 7<p>
<p> paragraph 8<p>
<p> paragraph 9<p>
<h3>title4</h3>
<p> paragraph 10<p>
<p> paragraph 11<p>
<p> paragraph 12<p>
```

How can I get data between `h3`'s, i.e

1. [paragraph1,paragraph2,paragraph3]
2. [paragraph4, paragraph5, data1, data2]
3. [paragraph6, paragraph7, paragraph8, paragraph9]
4. [paragraph10, paragraph11, paragraph12]

I used the following XPath:

1. `hdoc.xpath('h3[contains(.,"title1")]//following-sibling::*[following::*[self::h3]]//text()')`
2. `hdoc.xpath('h3[contains(.,"title2")]//following-sibling::*[following::*[self::h3]]//text()')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
hdoc.xpath("//p[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title1')] and ./following-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title2')]]/text()")

hdoc.xpath("//p[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title2')] and ./following-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title3')]]/text()")

hdoc.xpath("//p[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title3')] and ./following-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title4')]]/text()")

hdoc.xpath("//p[./preceding-sibling::h3[contains(text(),'title4')] and not(./following-sibling::h3)]/text()")
```

If you don't want to depend of the text of each h3, you can get them with the number of h3 each element has before:

```
# For elements between title1 and title2
hdoc.xpath('//p[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=1]/text() | //table[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=2]//td/text()')

# For elements between title2 and title3
hdoc.xpath('//p[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=2]/text() | //table[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=2]//td/text()')
...
```

Comment: Can't we do that common for all 4, without depending on the text of the tag?

Comment: @himabindu I edited the answer  with another approach

Comment: @himabindu added the table cells

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```xml
//text()[    preceding::h3[. = 'title1'] 
         and following::h3[. = 'title2']]
```

will select all of the text nodes between `h3` elements with given string values.